# Passing an *os.File as an *io.Reader

Tags: pointers, go

If there's a function that takes a *io.Reader, how would one pass an *io.File?  This doesn't work:

```
func somefunc(r *io.Reader){
}

func Test_FileReader(t *testing.T){
    f, err := os.Open("xyz")
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    somefunc(&f)
}
```

It gives this error:

> Cannot use '&f' (type **File) as type *io.Reader

Then, changing `*io.Reader`->`io.Reader` and `&f`->`f`, it compiles just fine:

```
func somefunc(r io.Reader){
}

func Test_FileReader(t *testing.T){
    f, err := os.Open("xyz")
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    somefunc(f)
}
```

Is it even possible to pass an *os.File as an *io.Reader??

Comment: Which function takes an `*io.Reader`? That would be an incredibly strange function.

Answer (score 4):

`*io.Reader` is a pointer to an interface. That is almost always unnecessary.

While `*File` is an `io.Reader`, `**File` is not `*io.Reader`. When the compiler passes a struct in place of an interface, it constructs an interface that contains the type and the value of the underlying value. However, `*io.Reader` is not an interface. So if you *really* want to pass a pointer to an interface, you have to first create an interface, and pass the address of it:

```
var intf io.Reader
intf=f
someFunc(&f)
```

But then, passing a pointer to an interface is only necessary if the function sets the interface value to something else.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to pass an *os.File as an *io.Reader?

No, of course not.

You seem to know that *os.File implement `io.Reader` and that `**os.File` does not. Note that you **never** *) need a pointer to interface.

*) There are cases when you need a pointer to interface and you will know when, its a *very* special and really uncommon case.